# How do I add/alter the shortcuts in the Rich Text Editor (RTE) of AEM?

Tags: text-editors, web-development, adobe-experience-manager

I have been using Adobe Experience Manager to create a large number of content pages. I manually click to edit the paragraph formatting options when I want a Header1 / Header2 / etc.

How do I go about editing the shortcuts in the RTE? In this particular instance it doesn't seem that paragraph formats have a shortcut, so I would be adding a new one. Is this feasible to do? I'm authoring about 2,000 web pages so it could save me a lot of time.